# how to profile memory usage of a celery task?

Tags: python, memory-management, celery, django-celery

I have a django application that runs background tasks using the celery lib and I need to obtain and store the max memory usage of a task.

I've tried memory_usage from memory_profiler library, but I can not use this function inside a task because I get the error: "daemonic processes not allowed have children". I've also tried the memory_usage function outside the task, to monitor the task.async call, but for some reason the task is triggered twice.

All the other ways I found out there consist of checking the memory usage in different places of the code and then getting the maximum, but I have the feeling that it is very inaccurate and there are probably some calls that have a high memory usage that is left out because of garbage collection before I manage to check the current memory usage.

the official documentation has some useful functions but it would have to rely on the method above. https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.utils.debug.html

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why not a `controller` tasks?

Celery infrastructure let to query the current status of all workers:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(...)
app.control.inspect().active()
```

This can be used inside a task to poll every # sec the cluster and understand what's happening.
I've used a similar approach to identify and send the `kill()` command between tasks. My tasks are killable so each of them know how to handle the soft kill.

Comment: How is this related to the question asked? Can you see the memory used by each worker in the controller?